# Sql query with substring filter to update data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What is the best way to use SUBSTRING method for UPDATE statement and condition!

```
UPDATE `store_results` SET `results_status` = "unpublished" WHERE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`results_trigger_on`,' ',1) AS resultdate FROM `store_results` HAVING resultdate BETWEEN '15/09/2018' AND '20/09/2018')
```

What will be the perfect query to achieve the same.

Comment: Field of date is set to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Kindly please stop string manipulations to calculate date and time. Use native [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime)'s instead:

```
$startInKolkata = new \DateTime(
    '2018-09-19 09:00:00',
    new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')
);

$endInWarsaw = new \DateTime(
    '2018-09-20 10:15:00', 
    new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw')
);

$dateDiff = $startInKolkata->diff($endInWarsaw);

printf(
    'Till end: %d day(s), %d hour(s), %d minute(s)',
    $dateDiff->d,
    $dateDiff->h,
    $dateDiff->i
);
```

The result of the `diff()` method is a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class, which holds all the information you would ever need about the difference.

Comment: My query is updated, what's wrong above. please tell me.

Comment: You keep the data in invalid format, thus MySQL is [unable to compare datetime values properly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html). Either rewrite the data and store datetime in proper format or use MySQL's [datetime functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to convert your format into [valid datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) one so the condition can work.